# MacBook - SSH wrong IP on connection

Tags: ssh

When I try to connect to my server using ssh with:

```
ssh -v -p PORT user@domain.com
```

I see:

```
OpenSSH_6.2p2, OSSLShim 0.9.8r 8 Dec 2011
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh_config line 20: Applying options for *
debug1: Connecting to domain.com [62.XX.XXX.157] port 10XXX
```

where the IP is wrong.

If I visit the site in the browser the domain point to the right IP.
If I try to access via FTP it is right.

How can I fix this?

Comment: Check your `/etc/ssh_config` for entries that would apply to `domain.com`.

Comment: What do you get when you resolve the domain.com with nslookup or something similar? Is it the same ip or something else? What about /etc/hosts, any remaining entries there?

Comment: @EEAA in that file I do not have any entries about domains.  
@Vladimir In `hosts`I just have my development site, that IP or domain is not present. If I use this: http://network-tools.com/nslook/ the IP is wrong, it points to the same of SSH, how is this possibile? My site is live and many clients use it. Should I post the wrong and right IPs?

Comment: what did you get if you "dig domain.com" and "telnet domain.com the_server_ssh_port"
If you are getting same ip, and is the wrong one, the problem is in the name resolution (dns, or any dns cache in the middle, such as a router)
If the ip differs between one command and the other, is a gethostbyname resolution problem (and then you should check, /etc/hosts, aliases, or any other that might be rewriting that resolution)

Comment: @ignivs I tried and the IP is the same and its wrong. How should I procede?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem. I have a mac with latest monterey version and a local network, that has both ipv4 and ipv6 stack in use!

Now I figured out, that if I use the hostname and not the ip Address, ssh tries ipv6 connection first. Im my case the ipv6 address pointed to a placeholder host in the fritzbox network, because the wanted host had no local v6 IP in the local dns. I added the ipv6 address in my local dns server. Since then it works.

You can easy check, if it is a ipv4 /v6 based problem.
test if you are reaching the right host with ipv4 if you try:

`ssh -v -4 user@hostname`

doublecheck the ipv6 connection:

`ssh -v -6 user@hostname`

If the destination differs, you have a ipv4 / ipv6 resolution problem.

In the ssh debug (-v) output line "Authenticated to ..." you see the destination IP-address, which the ssh client use as destination.

I hope, this can help someone, who is in the same trouble.

Comment: I had the same issue, in my case I was using a pi.hole to manage my DNS queries and it was only configured for ipv4. explicitly specifying `-4` made ssh resolve correctly, which helped me further triage the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry Christian, can't keep on comments because I have no enough reputation in superuser...

If dns resolution in general is wrong:

First, check dns, if it's wrong and you can change it, just change it
if dns is well defined but resolution is wrong, check what is the resolution ttl by issuing:

```
dig +nocmd +noall +answer +ttlid type subdomain.domain.com
```

let's say it answer

```
subdomain.domain.com   86400 the_wrong_ip
```

It'll mean it will be cached in DNSs for a day... so more than that is sign of a problem if is not resolving well.
Take a look on different DNSs to see if resolution problem is general.
You can do it with

```
dig @other_nameserver_ip subdomain.domain.com
```

Maybe the router in your network is caching a wrong ip or is obtaining a bad resolution, but the rest of the world is doing ok.
If you don't get any success, the I would do is adding the right ip to hosts file as ftp is using gethostbyname function, so it refers to hosts file before asking a dns; but if it has to be called by a third party... well

Hope some of the hints here helps you find the source of the problem

Answer (score 0):

I encountered this issue today on Mac OS X High Sierra; even though

```
host domain.com
```

returned the **correct IP address**, SSH still attempted to connect to an old version of the IP address. You can figure this out by adding a lot of `-v` flags to ssh, e.g.,

```
ssh -vvvv user@domain.com
OpenSSH_7.5p1, LibreSSL 2.5.4
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/razzed/.ssh/config
debug1: /Users/razzed/.ssh/config line 4: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh/ssh_config
debug1: /etc/ssh/ssh_config line 52: Applying options for *
debug2: resolving "domain.com" port 22
debug2: ssh_connect_direct: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to domain.com [XX.XX.XX.XX] port 22.
```

The issue is the IP address for that host is incorrectly cached in the Mac OS DNS cache and will appear differently than the `host` output in the `[XX.XX.XX.XX]` position above.

Neil Gee (of [Coolest Guides On The Planet](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com)) has an up-to-date way to [clear the local DNS cache in macOS](https://coolestguidesontheplanet.com/clear-the-local-dns-cache-in-osx/). As of today the command is:

```
sudo killall -HUP mDNSResponder
```

Once I did this, `ssh` connected correctly to the right IP address.